# How to limit the same request from being called

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs and I have route looks like this

/analyzeGame/${name}.

When someone send request to this route with the game name the analyzing function is called and the result of the analysis and ID of last player analyzed is stored in db. I don't await analysis to finish because it may take hours so I respond with
message :" starting to analyze ${game}"
My questions

1- How do I stop other functions of the same call to same game from being called, if I have 2 functions analyzing same game at same time database will be potentially corrupted

2- how do I halt the execution of an analysis. I want to make a request like

/stopAnalyzing/${game}

i thought of making global array holds running game names and check on it on every request is this even good?

No idea for the second question

Edit:

maybe change the array to array of objects to have boolean value and make every function check on it at the start and the call would just change that bool
But is there better solution don't know if global variables are good idea

Comment: You could supply a "ticket" as part of the form, some random number - and make sure it doesn't get accepted twice.

Comment: @callback so I add random number on the client side which will be sent with request to my server how can I make sure it doesn't get accepted twice since random

Comment: I guess you can store it in some cache on the server, and check if it exists in the cache before serving the request. and you delete it from the cache when the execution has completed.